# How to understand this type class error of telling me I use the wrong type?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

This is my function of calculating the average of a list of numbers

```
arithMean :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
arithMean list = (foldr (+) 0 list)/ (length list)
```

However, it raised an error below

```
HigherOrder.hs:10:39: error:
? Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      arithMean :: forall a. Fractional a => [a] -> a
    at HigherOrder.hs:9:1-39
? In the second argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘(length list)’
  In the expression: (foldr (+) 0 list) / (length list)
  In an equation for ‘arithMean’:
      arithMean list = (foldr (+) 0 list) / (length list)
? Relevant bindings include
    list :: [a] (bound at HigherOrder.hs:10:11)
    arithMean :: [a] -> a (bound at HigherOrder.hs:10:1)
```

About this error, I am very confused about why it forces me to change the "list" to [Int], I think no matter what types of it is, it should work

besides, I think maybe something happened when I try to use the "length" function because when I wrote this code below, it works

```
arithMean :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
arithMean list = (foldr (+) 0 list)
```

Comment: Dont get intimidated by complicated looking error messages. The error message literally tells you what is wrong. `Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’ ... In the second argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘(length list)’`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) means that the numerator and denominator need to be both need to have the same [**`Fractional`**](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Fractional) type.

[**`length :: [a] -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) however maps a foldable to an `Int`. An `Int` is *not* a `Fractional` type.

You can use [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) :: a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) here to convert the `Int` to an type that is a member of the [**`Num`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) typeclass.

```
arithMean :: (Fractional a, Foldable f) => f a -> a
arithMean list = sum list / fromIntegral (length list)
```

Instead of using `foldr (+) 0 list` here, we can use [**`sum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) here.